# gcc is not using /tmp for temporary files

Tags: linux, gcc

I am using Ubuntu Linux.

`gcc` is not using `/tmp` for temporary files (.i, .o, .s).

I exported environment variable `TMPDIR` like this:

```
export TMPDIR=/tmp
```

however `gcc` still tries to create tmp files in `./`
so, if there is no `W` permission, `gcc` fails.

So I want to fix the `gcc` temporary file path to `/tmp/`
however, gcc is ignoring the `TMPDIR`.

What would be the problem here?

Comment: What files GCC create in ./ ? I think tmp files means .s files in GCC(assuming you want to compile to .o).

Comment: `TMPDIR` is correct way, but why not just use `-pipe`? Besides, if there is no write permissions, where gcc should save generated output? What is full compilation line? (including exports)

Comment: I am having the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the:

`export TMPDIR=$HOME/temp;`

line to `~/.profile` file and then running:

```
. ~/.profile
```

command followed by a **system restart** did the trick for me in case anyone comes across this.